# Laravel infinite scroll and getting data from Api

Tags: javascript, laravel, scroll, infinite-scroll

Im getting data from api like this
its working but when srolled the bottom loading and component style looks js didnt load or notworking i dont know help me

```
Route::get('/newsfeed', function () {
    $path = Http::get('http:/api/mobile-app/v3/newsfeeds?page[number]=' . request('page', 1));

    if (request('page') > 1) {
        return view('layout.render-component', ['feeds' => $path]);
    }

    return view('newsfeed', ['feeds' => $path]);
});
```

My view:

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="container body">
            <div class="cont-half">
                <div style="background-color: white" class="rounded">
                    <div class="deed pt-5 pl-3">
                        <div class="today" style="margin: 2rem 0 0 0;">
                            <div class="title" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <label id="lblGreetings" class="greeting"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="infinite-scroll">
                    @include('layout.component')
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript Part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var i = 2;
            $(window).scroll(function() {

                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                    $.get('/newsfeed?page=' + i).then(function(data) {
                        $('.infinite-scroll').append(data);
                        i++;
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

And its working but when next page loading and component style looks js didnt load or notworking i dont know im new dev. help me pls im bad at javascript , what should i do ?
my result photo:

links: https://snipboard.io/msL12b.jpg

Comment: Use nested components for this may resolve your problem like so: Create a new view named page.component and return only this view as response, layout component should only be for contain page component. So no js and css files are nested again and again, this may crash your display.

Comment: @TamerDurgun yes i did, its didnt work and crashing